# Is there a way to get the name of the command from the message (Discord.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Usually when you create a command with the discord.py module, you do something like this:

```py
@commands.command(name="my_command", pass_context=True, aliases=["mc"])
def my_command(ctx):
    #Do some command action here
```

I want to be able to use my Discord bot to moderate commands so that commands can only be used in designated channels, e.g. "my_command" can only be used in #general.

One easy way to get the command name would be to do something like this:

```py
def get_command_name(message, prefix):
    command = message.split()[0].strip(prefix)
```

It would be nicer if I could used something like `message.command_used` to get the command, but I checked the documentation and there doesn't seem to be anything like that. Is there a way to get the command used from `context` rather than getting the command from string manipulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I checked the documentation and there doesn't seem to be anything like that

There is, in the docs for `commands.Context` you can find [`command`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#discord.ext.commands.Context.command) and [`invoked_with`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#discord.ext.commands.Context.invoked_with), both of which you can use to get the name of the command. In case you want to include possible subcommands, there's [`invoked_subcommand`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#discord.ext.commands.Command.invoked_subcommand) as well.

Comment: Ah, I see. I was looking under the API reference, not the discord.ext.commands API reference. Thank you!